# Return Input::except() multiple inputs in Laravel 4

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-4

I am working with Laravel 4,

I am validating a form with the validator :

`$validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);`

When it fails :

```
if ($validator->fails()) {
            return Redirect::to('register/test')
                            ->withErrors($validator)
                            ->withInput(Input::except('password')); // send back the input so that we can repopulate the form
        }
```

How can i return inputs excepting multiple inputs, not only the password ?

I've tried `Input::except('password','avatar');` but it's not working.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually, i found that i forget to put the `Input::old('')` to repopulate the input,

So the solution is exaclty what i've tried `Input::except('password','avatar');`

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
Input::except(array('password', 'avatar'));
```

Comment: I'm using laravel 4.2. Please look at \vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Http\Request.php in line 253 function except($keys) @param $keys is array